# What is the difference between getSocketAddress() and getAddress() in java.net.DatagramPacket

Tags: java, udp, datagram

What is the difference between `getSocketAddress()` and `getAddress()` in `java.net.DatagramPacket`? I tried to print out the contents from the received `DatagramPacket` and found they are the same.

Comment: No they aren't. `SocketAddress` contains a port number. `InetAddress` does not.

Comment: Thank you. It is real. But why the port number is different from the port I defined?

Comment: It is the *source* port, where the datagram came from. Try `getLocalSocketAddress()` and `getLocalAddress()` to see your own address:port.